# Let $I$ and $J$ be ideals, $(I+J)/I\subseteq (I+J)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $I$ and $J$ be ideal. We consider 
$$
\begin{split}
(I+J)/I:=&\{(i+j)+I\;|\;i\in I,j\in J\}\\
=&\{j+(i+I)\;|\;i\in I,j\in J\}\\
=&\{j+I\;|\;j\in J\}.
\end{split}
$$
Can I conclude from this that  $$(I+J)/I\subseteq (I+J).$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! No, the problem is if $I+J$ is an ideal in the ring $R$ then $(I+J)/I$ Is an ideal of the ring $R/I$.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to : is $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb Z$ that doesn't really make sense since you talk about two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to be more careful with your definitions. The elements in $(I + J)/I$ are equivalence classes of elements in $(I + J)$.

We say that two elements in $(I + J)/I$ are equivalent if they differ by something which lives in $I$.

As such, I think that we could say that for an equivalence class $x \in (I + J)/I$, $x \subseteq I+J$, but in general $(I + J)/I$ is not a subset of $I+J$.